Paying off large medical expense loan by using HSA
I am taking out a loan to pay for a medical expenditure that is a qualified medical expense.   The loan is one of the 0% for 2 years, so naturally I'd like to keep the money in HSA earning interest as much as possible.  Can I then use my HSA card to pay the monthly principal payments?   There will be a balloon principal after 2 years that I'd pay before the ridiculously high interest would take affect.
The HSA is already open when the medical expense is incurred.  I know that's a requirement.  I just can't tell if I am allowed to use HSA to pay off the loan. Part of the strategy here is also that my HSA account doesn't have enough to cover the expense at this time, but I'll continue to contribute over the next 2 years though my employer.  So it stretches out the medical expense and avoids some taxes if this is legal.

Lets start with the assumption that you can do this according to the rules.

Can I then use my HSA card to pay the monthly principal payments?

The system limits what type of vendors can accept the card. If the vendor type of the lender isn't accepted by the HSA system, you can't do this directly. You could use the option to pay yourself. They will want proof of the medical expense though bills or EOB's. I have never spread the payment over multiple withdraws but I understand it is allowable to do this.
Now back to determining if the expense can be paid from the HSA.
Since the procedure took place after the account was setup, and the expense would have been eligible to pay in one chunk if the funds were available; then it is acceptable.
For example if you start the HSA on 01 January, and have the procedure a few weeks later; It is unlikely that you would have had the much in the way of funds after a paycheck or two. It is acceptable to pay the balance as soon as you get the bill, but then withdraw the funds by paying yourself a few months later.
The loan isn't important, especially if there is no interest. You are using the loan to stretch out the due date, and then using the HSA to pay yourself back.
